# How to sync video (with dropped frames) with its separately recorded audio?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, sync

Video where frames get dropped:

```
procvid.StartInfo.Arguments = "-rtbufsize 1500M -f image2pipe -r 25 -i pipe:.bmp -vcodec libx264 -r 25 C:\\onlyvideo.avi"
```

Audio is recorded simultaneously with video:

```
procaud.StartInfo.Arguments = "-rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i audio=" + '"' + "Stereo Mix (Realtek High Defini" + '"' + " -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 48000 C:\\onlyaudio.wav";
```

Combine...result out of sync. Length of combined.avi is that of audio:

```
proccomb.StartInfo.Arguments = "-rtbufsize 1500M -i onlyvideo.avi -i onlyaudio.wav -vcodec copy -acodec copy C:\\combined.avi";
```

Is it possible to drop the audio packets corresponding to the dropped video frames?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the aresample filter and the framerate option for the input.

```
-rtbufsize 1500M -f image2pipe -framerate 25 -i pipe:.bmp \
-rtbufsize 500M -f dshow -i audio="Stereo Mix (Realtek High Defini" \
-af aresample=async=1
-c:v libx264 -r 25 -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 48000 C:\\test.avi
```